# Why can't I use attributes and methods of Dataset object after using dataset.take or dataset.skip or dataset.prefetch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, filepath, tensorflow-datasets, prefetch

I'm using tensorflow 2.6.4 from kaggle and i'm facing this issue:

I have made a dataset from which I generate other datasets.
After some transformations, I want to use some attributes of methods, but I got some errors that I don't understand how to overcome it.

Here is my code:

```
ds_full = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory( 
    directory = path_img_folder,
    seed=seed_state,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode = "categorical" 
)

ds_train = ds_full.take(train_size)    
ds_val = ds_full.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
ds_test = ds_full.skip(train_size).skip(val_size)

ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
ds_val = ds_val.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
ds_test = ds_test.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
```

when I type this, I got that error:

```
path_ds_test_img = ds_test.file_paths
print(path_ds_test_img)

AttributeError: 'SkipDataset' object has no attribute 'file_paths'
```

If I change the type of this dataset to get the same as ds_full, I also got that error:

```
ds_essai = ds_test.batch(batch_size = batch_size)
type(ds_essai)

tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset

ds_essai.file_paths
'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'file_paths'
```

However, it works with ds_full:

```
type(ds_full)
tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset

ds_full.file_paths

 /kaggle/input/dog-race-images/images/n02109047-Great_Dane/n02109047_2009.jpg',
 '/kaggle/input/dog-race-images/images/n02090622-borzoi/n02090622_8338.jpg',
 '/kaggle/input/dog-race-images/images/n02113978-Mexican_hairless/n02113978_2306.jpg',
...
```

What is the secret to get it working please?

Comment: The attribute `file_paths` is dropped after creating a different dataset based on some method. These methods do not support that attribute.